# Optimizing a LINQ query with multiple joins and predicates

Tags: c#, sql, performance, linq, entity-framework

Let's say that I have three tables in my SQL db - Users, Books, and UsersBooks.

I'm looking for ways to optimize the design/performance of a web method that takes a list of user names and returns a JSON object that contains users and their books.  I'm using Linq2Entities and SQL Server 2008.

Motivation for this question is that the web method is being called a lot (and growing!) so I need to find ways to make it run leaner and meaner.

Here's a stripped down version of the current design:

```
private string MyWebMethod(string input) {
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<string> userNames = serializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(input);

    using(var db = new dbContext()) {
        var usersAndBooks = from u in db.Users
                            join ub in db.UsersBooks on u.UserId equals ub.UserId
                            join b in db.Books on ub.BookId equals b.BookId
                            select new Result { User = u, UsersBooks = ub, Book = b };

        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Result>();

        // Construct predicate to filter usersAndBooks down to users we care about
        foreach(var name in userNames) {
            predicate = predicate.Or(r => r.User.UserName.Equals(name));
        }

        usersAndBooks = usersAndBooks.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);

        foreach(var name in userNames) {
            // Logic to construct final {User:{Books}} JSON object   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use `.Contains`?

```
var usersAndBooks = from u in db.Users
                    where userNames.Contains(u.UserName)
                    join ub in db.UsersBooks on u.UserId equals ub.UserId
                    join b in db.Books on ub.BookId equals b.BookId
                    select new Result { User = u, UsersBooks = ub, Book = b };
```

I think using linqkit / predicate builder / expression visitor is overkill here. You can essentially do a SQL `IN` clause using LINQ `.Contains`.

It's much easier for the database to optimize this:

```
WHERE User.UserName IN ('user1', 'user2', 'user3')
```

...than this:

```
WHERE User.UserName = 'user1' OR User.UserName = 'user2' OR User.UserName = 'user3'
```

Secondly, is it really necessary to loop over the results?

```
foreach(var name in userNames) {
    // Logic to construct final {User:{Books}} JSON object
}
```

... not sure what the logic is here, but you may be able to transform using just another .Select:

```
// Logic to construct final {User:{Books}} JSON object
var finalOutput = usersAndBooks.Select(x => new ...);
```

The only other thing I can recommend, other than caching or some other kind of fast data delivery service like redis, is using Newtonsoft JSON.Net instead of the JavaScriptSerializer:

```
List<string> userNames = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(input);
```

Comment: Thanks - Always best to keep it simple. Not seeing a significant perf gain from these changes but definitely a cleaner design!

Comment: In that case I think Pressacco's answer is going to be better for you. Either craft a custom SQL query or pre-compute the data and store it somewhere that can get it to you quickly.

Answer (score 2):

If performance is a concern, take a look at implementing a caching scenario that is appropriate for your website. the .net framework offers several options for caching, and there are several third party solutions to choose from.

Also, apart from choosing a caching technology, you should also decide on a caching strategy (whole page, only certain components within the page, etc.)

The trick is to only query the database when absolutely necessary.

CACHING TECHNOLOGIES

- [Asp.net - caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [memcached](http://memcached.org/)
- etc.

ADDITIONAL READING

- [High-Performance ASP.NET Caching](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/12/01/high-performance-aspnet-caching.aspx?m=2) (old, but still useful from high level)

Comment: Don't forget about redis!